# Batch file - Grabbing multiple lines from one ping

Tags: parsing, batch-file, ping

We are trying to prove to our internet company that our internet is out far more often than they say it is.
To do so, I'm writing a batch file to ping google.com once every (about) 15 minutes for 100 hours, and print the results to a text file. The only problem is that I want to grab the line that tells you how many packets succeeded/failed, as well as the times in ms line.
Here's what I have so far:

```
@echo off
set/a x=0
:A
echo %date% %time >> final.txt
ping google.com | Find "Mini" >> final.txt
timeout /t 900 /nobreak > NUL
set /a x+=1
if %x% LSS 400 goto :A
```

I could also pipe the ping result to a .txt, but I'm still not sure how to parse from there.

Comment: Why try to do this as a batch script? I always find scripts much easier to write in actual languages.

Comment: @Jashaszun: why not? The "best" language is not always the most actual. As I say: "use, what you know best"

Comment: @Stephan It's just that actual languages, like Python or C#, have such better string manipulation than batch file commands. String manipulation code in one of those two languages will just *always* be more clear than the same code in a batch file.

Comment: @Jashaszun batch script is the quickest and most accessible language for me, because our internet is currently iffy at best, and my dad is fairly fluent (but he's non-contactable at work right now and this was the last part I needed).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `findstr`instead. It is able to search for more than one string (separated by spaces):

```
ping google.com | Findstr "Minimum Pakete" >> final.txt
```

(you will have to translate "Minimum" and "Pakete" to your local language)

In your special case, you can also search for `<space>=<space>`:

```
ping google.com | Find " = " >> final.txt
```